# A Vector of Pointers and ifstream

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, ifstream

I am trying to read in data from a text file and store it as a class object I created called Movie. I also have to create a vector of pointers that point to each Movie. I used a while loop that reads until end of file and takes in the data as a Movie. Then I used a pointer to dynamically create a new Movie object which holds the data. It begins to start working and the vector stores a pointer that points to a Movie. After the 19th Movie though it just stops (there are about 300 movies I have to read in). I'm not sure why but I followed it in the debugger. There are no error codes. It just stops and the program does not continue to the end.

```
//Variables
string title;
//Open input stream
ifstream fin( "CS172_Spring2014_Movie_inputs.txt" ) ;

vector<Movie*> moviePtrList(350);

vector<Movie*>::iterator pos;
pos = moviePtrList.begin();

while(!fin.eof()) 
{
    getline(fin, title, '\n');
    Movie fileMovie(title);
    *pos = new Movie(movieFromFile(fin, fileMovie));

    pos++;
}
```

I also tried this method:

```
for(string title; getline(fin,title);) 
{
    /*getline(fin, title, '\n');*/
    Movie fileMovie(title);
    *pos = new Movie(movieFromFile(fin, fileMovie));

    pos++;
}
```

And this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<300;i++)
{
    getline(fin, title, '\n');
    Movie fileMovie(title);
    moviePtrList[i] = new Movie(movieFromFile(fin, fileMovie));
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

I also tried fin.good() instead of fin.eof(). No luck. This is the subprogram I used to read in from the text file:

```
Movie movieFromFile(ifstream &fin, Movie &inputMovie) 
{

Movie_Rating rating = G;
string actor, director, path, inputRating, separator="$$$$";
unsigned int year, actors;

getline(fin, director, '\n');
inputMovie.setDirector(director);

fin >> year;
fin.ignore();
inputMovie.setYear(year);

getline(fin, inputRating, '\n');
if (inputRating == "G") {
    rating = G ;
} else if (inputRating == "PG") {
    rating = PG ;
} else if (inputRating == "PG13") {
    rating = PG13 ;
} else if (inputRating == "R") {
    rating = R ;
} else if (inputRating == "NC17") {
    rating = NC17 ;
} else if (inputRating == "NR") {
    rating = NR ;
}
inputMovie.setRating(rating) ;
fin.ignore();

getline(fin, path, '\n');
inputMovie.setURL(path);

do {
    getline(fin, actor, '\n');
    inputMovie.addActor(actor);
} while(actor != separator);

return inputMovie;


}
```

I hope this is not too much text. I probably made a stupid mistake somewhere or overlooked something. I'm going to sleep on it and attack it again in the morning, rewrite the subprogram, and read some more material. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Starting out.. [`while(!fin.eof())` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). Once you fix that, try checking your input success/failure pretty much *everywhere* rather than assuming they worked. Beyond that I see no reason not to simply use a `std::vector<Movie>`. Unless you have polymorphic plans, those pointers are more a nuisance than anything else, and even with polymorphism, they should be smart pointers.

Comment: And testing `.good()` isn't the solution either.  Test the return value from `getline()`, so that errors that happen during getline can be detected.

Comment: @seminole2r `There are no error codes. It just stops and the program does not continue to the end`  C++ doesn't work that way, where you will get "error codes" when you have a faulty program.  There are a lot of things wrong with your program, reading the input is the least of them.

Comment: WhozCraig thank you. I inserted fin.fail() but 0 errors came up.
Ben Voight thank you as well. I used while(getline(fin,title)) but still stopping at 19.
http://i.imgur.com/Nf9pEmY.jpg

Comment: Thanks PaulMcKenzie, I will rewrite this whole thing then.

Comment: @seminole2r - Don't just rewrite it.  Understand what you are doing wrong now, so that if/when you do rewrite it, you understand what each line is doing.  `I also tried this method:`  That indicates that you're throwing lines of code at the compiler and hoping something works.  If someone were to ask you to describe each line of your attempt and what each line was doing, could you explain what is occurring?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - Yes. Is there a specific line? Could you point out what is wrong or just the general mistakes if the list is too extensive?

Comment: @seminole2r [See this link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4e4e1ec08677338) for a **basic** sample of how to do what you're trying. I don't understand why your instruction is having you load pointers into an array (as opposed to *objects* into a *vector*) but its not the oddest thing I've seen from academia. Another example that avoids pointers and just used a vector of objects [**can be seen here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3aa42a77a1506b1). Anyway, best of luck.

Comment: Do you still need an answer?

Comment: Thank you WhozCraig
@david.pfx - I am just beginning to work on it again. If you have any more input it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the attempts appears to suffer from the same core problem: a misunderstanding about the difference between pointers and objects.

The proper way to use a vector is to push an object onto it. Often, it's necessary to create that object first. What is mostly *not* necessary is to use pointers or iterators. So your code might look like:

```
vector<Movie> movieList();
...
getline(fin, title, '\n');
Movie fileMovie(title);
moveList.push(fileMovie);
```

Think in terms of objects, not pointers. What you are doing is undefined behaviour and it's not surprising it fails mysteriously after a while. C++ does that.

There are other problems with the code (see comments) but I think this is the reason it dies. Fix this and maybe ask another question.